# HtML Footnote appears behind an element

Tags: html, css, footnotes

*Newbie here*

I'm making a website that has 2 main sections: one larger section (section A) with 75% width, and another section (section B) with 25% width, appear side by side.

Section A has several p tags with footnote inside, the only problem is that when I hover the footnote, it appears behind the section B, can anybody help me? Thanks!

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXjZG.jpg

CSS Code:

```
Section A {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
}
Section B {
    float: right;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: left;
}
Footnote-sign {
    background-color: #ffc;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: super;
    font-size: 77%;
}
Footnote-tooltip {
    background-color: #fea; 
    border: 1px solid #6b0000; 
    display: inline; 
    padding: 5px; 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 85%;
    max-width: 540px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a `z-index` to the footnote element to make it appear to be above every other element, without the `HTML` I will just apply the `z-index` to both footnote `CSS` elements

CSS

```
Footnote-sign {
    background-color: #ffc;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: super;
    font-size: 77%;
    z-index: 100; /* a large number to ensure it's on top */
}
Footnote-tooltip {
    background-color: #fea; 
    border: 1px solid #6b0000; 
    display: inline; 
    padding: 5px; 
    display: none; 
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 85%;
    max-width: 540px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 100; /* a large number to ensure it's on top */
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I will only need the -tooltip to have z-index because the -sign is just the number indicating a footnote.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `z-index` to the Footnote-tooltip

```
Footnote-tooltip {
z-index:100;
}
```

Comment: welcome.. Give the upvote if it worked. So that it'll be helpful for someone else

Comment: I did, but I don't have enough reputation to make it appear publicly xD

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this without z-index then follow my pen.

Hope this pen will help you.

```
'http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGeaKp'
```